# androidx migration problem with several libraries

Tags: android, androidx

I have migrated to androidx recently and faced these problems.

Problem :

[image]
[image]

**My configuration**

*build.gradle(app) :*

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.crazy.tuhin.aroundme"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    //google
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'


}
```

*build.gradle(project) :*

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*gradle-wrapper.properties :*

```
#Fri Apr 10 02:21:34 IST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

*settings.gradle :*

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

*My android studio version :*

> Android Studio 3.6.2

My question is do I have to change every import manually? but I have this `android.enableJetifier=true`

Can you please point out the problem? The already mentioned problems and solutions here are not helping.
Thanks.

Comment: Select Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti
Yes I followed that step to migrate

Comment: Remove the v7/support import and update with the new imports

Answer (score 0):

> My question is do I have to change every import manually?

Yes, you've to.

`android.enableJetifier=true` helps migrate third-party dependencies to use AndroidX. Jetifier will change the byte code of those dependencies to make them compatible with projects using AndroidX.

Following are the proper steps to migrate -

**Preparing to migrate**

Before you start to migrate to AndroidX you should:

- Create a new branch on which to make the migration changes.
- If possible, suspend or minimize development ( at least don’t try to do refactoring or pull in new features ) during the migration, as this will help reduce the number of merge conflicts that could happen.

**Migrate**

Throughout the migration steps focus on addressing errors, getting your app to compile, and passing all tests.

> Step 1:

Migrating directly to AndroidX from an older version of the Support Library, say 26 or 27, isn’t recommended. Bring the app up to date. Update the project to use the final version of the support library: [version 28.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#28-0-0). This is because AndroidX artifacts with version `1.0.0` are binary equivalent to the Support Library `28.0.0` artifacts. **Then address all of the API changes, and ensure your app compiles with version 28.**

> Step 2:

Update third-party dependencies to the latest. Not doing so could result in unexplained compilation errors.

> Step 3:

Enable the following flags in `gradle.properties`. With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to **AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

`android.enableJetifier=true`  - Jetifier helps migrate third-party dependencies to use AndroidX. Jetifier will change the byte code of those dependencies to make them compatible with projects using AndroidX.

`android.useAndroidX=true`  - The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

If you run into an unfortunate problem like mine, do these:

**1.** Delete all unused imports (grey coloured) from every class.

[image]

**2.** Now import the required classes like this :

[image]

**3.** Repeat for every related class.